# how to Json string from MySQL field contains double quotes Error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, utf-8

I have some error in json string that comes from mysql database field

```
{"videoshow":{"id":"4058517","title":"\u062c\u0634\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0633\u06cc\u0646 - \u0646\u06cc\u0645 \u0646\u06af\u0627\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0645\u0631\u06cc\u062e\u06cc (THE MARTIAN)","username":"saros.magazine","userid":"650163","visit_cnt":724,"uid":"26eAX","process":"done","sender_name":"\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u0627\u0644 \u0639\u0644\u0645\u06cc \u0633\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0633","big_poster":"http:\/\/static.asset.aparat.com\/\/avt\/4058517-3577-b__200242495.jpg","small_poster":"http:\/\/static.asset.aparat.com\/\/avt\/4058517-3577__99999.jpg","profilePhoto":"http:\/\/static.aparat.com\/public\/user_data\/profile_photo\/217\/650163-m.jpg?217","duration":"307","sdate":"4 \u0641\u0631\u0648\u0631\u062f\u06cc\u0646 1395","sdate_timediff":12063124,"frame":"http:\/\/www.aparat.com\/\/video\/video\/embed\/videohash\/26eAX\/vt\/frame","video_cnt":"21","official":"no","flv_name":"4cd5c29375ec34e96ffa34c7b01e935f4058517","tags":[{"name":"\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0633\u06cc\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc","cnt":"1760"},{"name":"\u0633\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0633","cnt":"14"},{"name":"\u062c\u0634\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0633\u06cc\u0646","cnt":"10"}],"tag_str":"\u062c\u0634\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0633\u06cc\u0646-\u0633\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0633-\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0633\u06cc\u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc","description":"\u062f\u0631 \u062f\u0648\u0645\u06cc\u0646 \u0633\u0631\u0649 \u0627\u0632 \u062c\u0634\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u0631\u0648\u0632\u0649 "\u0633\u06cc\u0646" \u0628\u0647 \u0633\u0631\u0627\u063a \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc "\u0645\u0631\u06cc\u062e\u06cc" \u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u06cc\u0645. \u062f\u0631 \u0631\u0648\u0632 \u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u0631\u06cc \u062f\u0648\u0645 \u060c \u0645\u0627\u0646\u0646\u062f \u0633\u0631\u06cc \u0642\u0628\u0644 \u0628\u0627 \u0622\u0642\u0627\u0649 \u062f\u0643\u062a\u0631 \u0646\u0648\u0631\u0648\u0632\u0649 \u0647\u0645\u0631\u0627\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u06cc\u0645. \u0647\u0645 \u0627\u06a9\u0646\u0648\u0646 \u0645\u06cc\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u062f \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0632 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u06cc\u0645\u0648 \u0645\u0634\u0627\u0647\u062f\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc\u062f ! \nhttp:\/\/filimo.com\/m\/pa1ny\n\u0628\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc\u062f \u0648 \u0644\u0630\u062a \u0628\u0628\u0631\u06cc\u062f ! \u0633\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u062b\u0644 \u0633\u06cc\u0646\u0645\u0627 ... \u0633\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u062b\u0644 \u0633\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0633","cat_id":10,"cat_name":"\u0639\u0644\u0645 \u0648 \u062a\u06a9\u0646\u0648\u0644\u0648\u0698\u06cc","autoplay":false,"video_date_status":"notset","preview":{"type":"video","src":"http:\/\/www.aparat.com\/public\/public\/images\/test\/v1.mp4"},"file_link":"https:\/\/hw14.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/a_6chie7fh4159k7jhn56j18kkf56h9g23j157k6270739-582u__52da4.apt?was=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OC8xMC8yMDE2IDY6Mzg6NDEgQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1OcnNQUzg0Zlo2eE9xTTZ5bVNqOEpBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTE0NDAwJmlkPWV5SnplWE5mYm1GdFpTSTZJbUZ3WVhKaGRDSXNJblJwYldVaU9qRTBOekE0TVRFeE1qRXNJblpwWkNJNk5EQTFPRFV4Tnl3aWQyRjBZMmhmZEhsd1pTSTZJbVJ2ZDI1c2IyRmtJaXdpZG1semFYUmZjMk52Y0dVaU9qVXNJbkp1WkhWelpYSnBaQ0k2SWpRd05UZzFNVGN4TkRjd09ERXhNVEl4TlRJeU9EYzNJaXdpZFhObGNsOXBjQ0k2SWpRMkxqSXlOUzR5TkRJdU1qSTVJaXdpWkhWeVlYUnBiMjRpT2lJek1EY2lMQ0oxYzJWeWFXUWlPaUkyTlRBeE5qTWlmUT09","file_link_all":[{"profile":"270p","urls":["https:\/\/hw7.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/a_2cmn3fm07i15k3omn12o74ppk12m5l89o713p2836395-058z__a852d.apt?was=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OC8xMC8yMDE2IDY6Mzg6NDEgQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1OcnNQUzg0Zlo2eE9xTTZ5bVNqOEpBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTE0NDAwJmlkPWV5SnplWE5mYm1GdFpTSTZJbUZ3WVhKaGRDSXNJblJwYldVaU9qRTBOekE0TVRFeE1qRXNJblpwWkNJNk5EQTFPRFV4Tnl3aWQyRjBZMmhmZEhsd1pTSTZJbVJ2ZDI1c2IyRmtJaXdpZG1semFYUmZjMk52Y0dVaU9qVXNJbkp1WkhWelpYSnBaQ0k2SWpRd05UZzFNVGN4TkRjd09ERXhNVEl4TlRJeU9EYzNJaXdpZFhObGNsOXBjQ0k2SWpRMkxqSXlOUzR5TkRJdU1qSTVJaXdpWkhWeVlYUnBiMjRpT2lJek1EY2lMQ0oxYzJWeWFXUWlPaUkyTlRBeE5qTWlmUT09","http:\/\/as6.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/4cd5c29375ec34e96ffa34c7b01e935f4058517-270p__89545.apt"]},{"profile":"360p","urls":["https:\/\/hw14.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/a_6chie7fh4159k7jhn56j18kkf56h9g23j157k6270739-582u__52da4.apt?was=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9OC8xMC8yMDE2IDY6Mzg6NDEgQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1OcnNQUzg0Zlo2eE9xTTZ5bVNqOEpBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTE0NDAwJmlkPWV5SnplWE5mYm1GdFpTSTZJbUZ3WVhKaGRDSXNJblJwYldVaU9qRTBOekE0TVRFeE1qRXNJblpwWkNJNk5EQTFPRFV4Tnl3aWQyRjBZMmhmZEhsd1pTSTZJbVJ2ZDI1c2IyRmtJaXdpZG1semFYUmZjMk52Y0dVaU9qVXNJbkp1WkhWelpYSnBaQ0k2SWpRd05UZzFNVGN4TkRjd09ERXhNVEl4TlRJeU9EYzNJaXdpZFhObGNsOXBjQ0k2SWpRMkxqSXlOUzR5TkRJdU1qSTVJaXdpWkhWeVlYUnBiMjRpT2lJek1EY2lMQ0oxYzJWeWFXUWlPaUkyTlRBeE5qTWlmUT09","http:\/\/as6.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/4cd5c29375ec34e96ffa34c7b01e935f4058517-360p__89545.apt"]}],"videovisit":"http:\/\/www.aparat.com\/etc\/api\/videovisit\/videohash\/26eAX\/utime\/757_1470811121\/hutime\/4fcec5fb6235287a4cc3a0863261384be6f94cc8","videovisitcall_time":5,"hls":{"enable":false,"link":null},"playeradvert":"","playeradvert_src":"http:\/\/aparat.ads.sabavision.com\/showads.php?posid=850&w=100%&h=100%&force_fit=yes&bg=000&ios_ad=yes","playeradvert_time":4,"like":{"status":"no","link":"http:\/\/www.aparat.com\/etc\/api\/videolikeset\/videohash\/26eAX\/code3\/786559717\/luser\/\/ltoken\/\/devicetype\/atrty\/1470811121\/avrvy\/\/\/key\/de73a1ddfcd09ee28dbc181f6262d0c55cfb7d44"},"share":{"status":"login","link":null},"playeradvertcornel":"","has_comment":"yes","has_comment_txt":"","size":"20329949","watch_action":{"type":"watch"},"cost_type":{"type":"free"},"can_download":true,"like_cnt":16,"follow_link":null,"follow_status":null}}
```

in description item from json object string contains double quotes and I can't Handle it with PHP `json_decode()` function .

how can I handle the jsons strings like this ? also my json's strings has some utf-8 content

Comment: Just saw this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38867411/5357503 may help

Comment: your json is invalid validate at http://jsonlint.com/ then json_decode

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: I know my json is not valid . this json string becom from mysql field and I just can escape it afer retrieving

Comment: I should clear description part from " double quotation " but in PHP it doesn't work with preg_replace or str_replace at all

Comment: See [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/617/json/2019/encoding-a-json-string#t=201608121525470362504) for how to get utf8 instead of unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is encoding special characters to unicode format while you are storing data to your mysql table. Can you please share your code snippet which you have used to store this JSON data in mysql?

You basically need to handle JSON format properly while you are storing, this will ease the process of fetching data from the table.

Thanks